# Benz automatic transmission almost stalls engine when cold

Tags: automatic-transmission, mercedes-benz, stall, hesitation

i have a 1992 Mercedes W140 300se automatic transmission and v6 engine. My issue is that when i start the car in the morning and shift to drive and give it some gas, the engine shudders and feels like its about to stall. It doesnt stall, there is a lag before the car takes off

The car hesitates and the only way to get the car moving is to give it a lot of gas, upto 2k rpm, then it leaps forward.

This happens until i travel about 1km and then everything is normal...pulls fine, no more lag, it runs like a champ. It feels like when the tranny has been running for some time, everything returns to normal.

Could it be the fuel pump? The fuel pressure regulator? The maf? Crankshaft position sensor? Or vacuum lines? Or the tranny itself?? :( it pulls really good and its not slipping at all.

There are no fault codes from obd.

Ive done some maintenance on the car and it improved slightly, changed the fuel filter, spark plugs, air filter and new engine oil.

Thanks and i hope you can advise me on the next course of action... i love this car and its always been very reliable. I am willing to spend the money to get it all back to normal :(

Comment: I forgot to mention, transmission fluid is on the level, not overfilled, and the fluid looks brand new; no burnt smell and is not dark in color.

Comment: Another observation is that in the morning, its like it has asthma...its like it cant breathe... seriously.... weve changed and checked the maf and it was fine

Comment: See and did you check for air leaks ? https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/64530/10976